# Sitewide authentication error - only in IE7/8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have a restful authentication, rails 2.2.2 app I'm getting ready to launch, but getting weird behavior when I hit the site from IE7 or 8 (not FF 3.5, 3, Mac or PC): hitting the domain http://startuptodo.com in IE7 gets you an IE dialog:

Connect to startuptodo.com
the server startuptodo.com at Web Password requires a username and password.
Warning: This server is requesting that your username and password be sent in an insecure manner (basic authentication without a secure connection).
then flds to enter your user name and password.

If you cancel, you get a blank page save for: HTTP Basic: Access denied.

Same thing happens for https://startuptodo.com.

If FF, you go to the login page as you should.

Totally stumped - any and all answers welcome!

Comment: Just curious: Why is this community wiki?

Comment: probably because I didn't know what community wiki meant - I thought it meant letting other SO members improve my question...No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting a basic auth login box instead of a re-direct to the login page? Most likely, this should solve it for you: http://www.twistingmaze.com/blog/2009/02/25/restful-authentication-bug-internet-explorer/

Cheers.

Comment: This was exactly it - and a good reason to go with Authlogic!